# Why playbook take wrong values for group variables?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a problem with groups variables.
   Example: I have two inventory groups  group_A  and group_B, and also have  the same name files in group_vars:

```
inventories/ 
           hosts.inv    
             [group_A]
               server1
               server2
             [group_B]
               server3
               server4
             group_vars/
                  group_A - file
                    var_port: 9001
                  group_B - file
                    var_port: 9002
```

The problem is when i execute:

```
 ansible-playbook  playbooks/playbook.yml -i inventories/hosts.inv -l group_B
```

playbook was executed for proper scope of servers (server3,  server4) but it takes variables from group variables file group_A.

```
    expected result:        var_port: 9002
    in realty :             var_port: 9001
```

ansible 2.4.2.0

BR Oleg

Comment: could you please ensure you don´t have that variable somewhere else? I have tested your scenario with 2.4.2 and works fine:

---
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

  - name: Print Var
    debug:
      var: var_port

TASK [Print DBs (Raw)] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [server3] => {
    "var_port": 9002
}
ok: [server4] => {
    "var_port": 9002
}

Comment: Agree with @imjoseangel: as presented, your usecase should work. You can try to check your inventory configuration with the [`ansible-inventory`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-inventory.html) and the options `--graph` and `--vars`

Comment: when I disabled  variable  var_port in file group variables "group_A" ( with #) my playbook take right variable value 9002, from group_var file  " group_B".  
It is look like playbook run through all group_files take first  one and did not filter by group   condition (in my case group_B)

Comment: I include ANSIBLE_DEBUG   2018-05-03 15:23:23,663 p=129458 u=user |  129458 1525353803.66336: Loading data from /ansible/inventories/prod/group_vars/p_dseoper.yml
2018-05-03 15:23:23,663 p=129458 u=user |  129661 1525353803.66060: in run() - task 00505680-eccc-d94e-2b1b-0000000000f4
2018-05-03 15:23:23,664 p=129458 u=user |  129661 1525353803.66458: calling self._execute()
2018-05-03 15:23:23,665 p=129458 u=user |  129458 1525353803.66589: Loading data from /ansible/inventories/prod/group_vars/t_dseoper.yml

Answer (score 4):

I included ANSIBLE_DEBUG , and what i have found:

2018-05-03 15:23:23,663 p=129458 u=user |  129458 1525353803.66336: Loading data from /ansible/inventories/prod/group_vars/**group_B.yml**
2018-05-03 15:23:23,663 p=129458 u=user |  129661 1525353803.66060: in run() - task 00505680-eccc-d94e-2b1b-0000000000f4
2018-05-03 15:23:23,664 p=129458 u=user |  129661 1525353803.66458: calling self._execute()
2018-05-03 15:23:23,665 p=129458 u=user |  129458 1525353803.66589: Loading data from /ansible/inventories/prod/group_vars/**group_A.yml**

**on playbook execution ansible scan all files with variables in folder group_vars which have variable "var_port", last will win.....**

*as you can found in another topic: 
[Ansible servers/groups in development/production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278370/ansible-servers-groups-in-development-production/40280199#40280199)*

*and from documentation: 
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable*

```
Note

Within any section, redefining a var will overwrite the previous instance. If multiple groups have the same variable, **the last one loaded wins**. If you define a variable twice in a play’s vars: section, the **2nd one wins**.
```

For me now NOT clear how to manage configuration files. In this case I must use unique variables names for each group, but it is not possible regarding roles, or  should  I use include_vars when i call playbook?

Comment: Colorful example https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-multistage-environments-with-ansible#ansible-recommended-strategy-using-groups-and-multiple-inventories

Comment: this still seems the most natural way to set the variables and is unsupported, what was you final solution?

Answer (score 1):

Super example how to manage variables files in multistage environment from DigitalOcean
[How to Manage Multistage Environments with Ansible](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-multistage-environments-with-ansible#ansible-recommended-strategy-using-groups-and-multiple-inventories)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem here, while not explicitly stated in the original question, is that Server{1,2} and Server{3,4} are actually the same servers in 2 different groups at the same level.

I ran into this problem which caused me to do some digging. I don't agree with it, but it is as designed. This was even fixed with full compatibility and the pull request was rejected

[Discussion](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9065)

[Pull Request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/6666)